# How to select two record set only if second one was successful?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I am going to report result of a stored procedure (whether it was successful or has error) using a simple select statement before sending prepared record sets. so I just simply insert this select statement before sending real records sets. But even when I wrap these two select statement in a transaction to make them atomic yet if second select statement raises an error the first select executed and gives 'ok' and 'error' at the same time. here is the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure
  @id INT = NULL
AS
  BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
      BEGIN TRANSACTION;
      SELECT 1 AS [status], 'OK' AS [message];

      SELECT 1/0;
      COMMIT;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
      ROLLBACK;
      SELECT 0 AS [status], ERROR_MESSAGE() AS [message];
    END CATCH;
  END;
```

How could first select statement be done only if the the second statement is successful?

Comment: See http://www.dbdelta.com/the-curious-case-of-undetected-sql-exceptions/. I don't understand what you mean by prepared records sets. I suggest you raise an error to indicate failure and/or use a non-zero stored procedure return code.

Comment: @DanGuzman, Thanks for article link. by prepared record sets i mean those record sets which are the last and actually the result record sets expected by executing stored procedure. I was thinking transaction would rollback first select on subsequent error raising but seems i was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe declare a couple of variables outsite of the `TRY/CATCH`. Then change their values in the `CATCH` if an error is thrown. After the `TRY/CATCH`, show the values of the variables.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE my_procedure
  @id INT = NULL
AS
  BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;
    DECLARE @status BIT = 1; --set status variable here
    DECLARE @message VARCHAR(MAX) = 'OK'; --set message variable here

    BEGIN TRY
      BEGIN TRANSACTION;

      SELECT 1/0;
      COMMIT;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
      ROLLBACK;
      SET @status = 0; --change value of @status in the CATCH block
      SET @message = ERROR_MESSAGE();--change value of @message in the CATCH block
    END CATCH;
    --show the value of each variable
    SELECT @status AS 'Status',@message AS 'Message'
  END;
```

Comment: Tanx. Actually the application layer, tests against first record set for status; Seems we should change that to check last record set if we want to remain this format.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using RAISERROR() or THROW()? Specifically, using RAISERROR() with a severity of 11-19 will force the execution to jump to the CATCH block. See details at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql.

Specifically take a look at Example 1:

```
BEGIN TRY  
    -- RAISERROR with severity 11-19 will cause execution to   
    -- jump to the CATCH block.  
    RAISERROR ('Error raised in TRY block.', -- Message text.  
               16, -- Severity.  
               1 -- State.  
               );  
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);  
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;  
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;  

    SELECT   
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),  
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),  
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();  

    -- Use RAISERROR inside the CATCH block to return error  
    -- information about the original error that caused  
    -- execution to jump to the CATCH block.  
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.  
               @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.  
               @ErrorState -- State.  
               );  
END CATCH;
```

Comment: Of course i've tried em. but the question was how to issue a status message to determine stored procedure execution result using select statement.